# Deploy WAR file in Tomcat, Issue after Deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a web application using `JSP & Servlet.(IDE: Eclipse, Container: Tomcat7.0)`

To learn deployment, I have made `war` file of project to deploy on Tomcat7.0. and I was able to deploy it on Tomcat server. Later on I was also able to access it from My Computer and also from other computers in the LAN.

Then I started using Eclipse to make changes in that application. While working in Eclipse, and when I try to access Deployed Application from other computers it is showing me the same application, but it is giving me the modified output as I have done changes in eclipse to the same project. I am using the same server in Eclipse.

My question is that why it is showing me the current output, and not showing the  output of Deployed Application when Tomcat server in Eclipse is ON.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are saying that your changes to the application is getting reflected on the server. If you dont want it to happen dont deploy it on the server or use a different server.

Comment: In eclipse you need to shut down the tomcat server and run out side

Comment: Yes, using different server will solve the problem. But I don't understand why it is showing output of Application in Eclipse, rather than showing output of Deployed Application.

Comment: @swamy : Yes, if I shutdown the server from Eclipse, and start from outside, then it is showing me the output of deployed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the development stage and want to modify the application code while the application already deployed on the server then you need to update changes to the server where the application is deployed. If it's classes you have to reload classes if it JSP just update resources. As far as I know the free version of Eclipse allows only redeploy the application and not any subsequent changes.

Again, in the free version of Eclipse the Tomcat server could only be configured as remote one whenever you run it locally or remotely inside or outside of Eclipse. And it modifies Tomcat server configuration to run your application if you deployed to ROOT.

Comment: i agree with this..just try to redeploy the updated war file..and restart the server for any changes to be reflected..

Comment: @Roman C & Lakshmanan : Yes, I am aware that I will need to update changes to the server where the application is deployed, but my question is that when the server in eclipse in on then it shows the output of the project which is in Eclipse, and when Tomcat is on from outside of Eclipse it shows output of deployed application

Comment: the output of the project is redirected to eclipse when you launch it from there

Answer (score 0):

Because both eclipse server  and  the  deployed server pointing to localhost only ..