# Struts2: URL action relative path

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a created an struts2 tags url. something like this.

```
<s:url action="login" var="login_url">
</s:url>
```

Upon Seeing the generated HTML. it gave me this

```
<a href="/MyProjectName/login">login</a>
```

Which is something I Do not like. I all I want to see is this

```
<a href="login">login</a>
```

It is currently giving me the full project name. is there a way I can prevent this when using struts2

Comment: Are you sure is this namespace not the context?

Comment: @RomanC What do you mean?

Comment: I mean MyProjectName could be namespace if you deployed to the ROOT. And I asked what's this.

Comment: Oh, MyProjectName is not a namespace. I am using the default namespace . I have updated my question.

Comment: Look at your question where "currently giving me the full namespace"

Comment: @RomanC oops, forgot about that. I have updated it

Comment: you should distinguish between webapp context name and namespace, are you?

Comment: either of them are part of the uri

Comment: And I needed to know which one

Comment: but different parts, the project name could be as context name but not as namespace name

Comment: @RomanC Okay I got it. the generated url '/MyProjectName/' is the context itself.  while 'login' is the uri. even though I set includeContext  = "false". the generated url still has this '/' before the login. like this '/login' which I want to eliminate

Comment: why, you will not be able to execute action without context, that slash state that you have not context

Comment: because, whenever I use an ajax request on it together with HTML5 PUSH state. the Url becomes like this localhost:8090/MyProjectName/#/MyProjectName/login. because of the context.  what I am aiming is localhost:8090/MyProjectName/#/login.

Comment: then you don't need includeContext, use value="login" in the url tag

Comment: @RomanC it worked. is there a way I can select oyur answer as the best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is deployed in that context.  You need it to get the url to work.  If the context is not present you will get 404 errors.  You should deploy your application as a ROOT application to not show that context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-in-tomcat-in-the-root.  For jboss, you deploy in ROOT.war

Comment: I did deploy on root but it is still having a 404 error.  the error seems to be the '/' before the href.

Comment: If you use the struts2 s:a tag correct you should not have this problem.  Make sure includeContext="true" or leave that option out.  The default is correct. If you deployed it wrong it might be in the /root context.    All the urls in our application start with a '/'

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the '/' ? because I am currently using AJAX to load its contents together with Push state. when the <a> tag is clicked the page cannot be loaded. however if I add the context in the url the page loads but the url looks messy.

Comment: Wait, Why ROOT.war? I am using Eclipse. how would  I achieve this?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109735/deploy-war-file-in-tomcat-issue-after-deployment/14109873#14109873)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the attribute `includeContext` to `false`
so that

```
<s:url action="login" var="login_url" includeContext="false">
</s:url>
```

For more reference, [check this](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but upon clicking the link it gave me a 404 the url went something like this. http://localhost:8090/login . is there anyway to remove the extra / ? on the generated url

Comment: There's still an extra slash in the before the url after I've set the includeContext="false" is there anyway I can remove it?